# nib files visible in iOS8 Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios8, ios-frameworks

I am creating an iOS8 Cocoa Touch framework. The final .framework directory is showing nib files. Is that expected behavior?

I want to hide as much code details as possible except .h files.

[image: .nib files visible in .framework seen with Finder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nib... (Next Interface Builder) files are what your xibs are converted to for the runtime system... (they used to be the only thing... before apple introduced the xibs)... frameworks don't need to have them, but if your framework has UI elements it is probably a very convenient way to package them...

if you make all of your UI elements programmatically, then you won't need them at all

Comment: I understand what they are but I been under the assumption that they won't be shown inside a .framework package ?

Comment: @2cupsOfTech do you reference your xibs in your code?... it is possible they are empty... in which case you don't need them... but if you created UI elements in xibs, then that data is stored in the nib, and that data is used to deserialize your UI... and it IS required

Comment: @2cupsOfTech... then the nibs need to exist in the bundle... the only way around that is to refactor to create all of your UI elements programmatically